# How to install an old Logitech QuickCam 4000 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, logitech-webcam

How can I install a Logitech Quickcam 4000 (V-UJ16) on a Windows 10 computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this tutorial for the Logitech QuickCam 5000, and with a tweak it also works for the 4000.

https://www.nerd-quickies.net/2019/10/15/logitech-quickcam-pro-5000-under-windows-10/

**BUT**: To work with the QuickCam 4000 you have to download **qc1051deu_x64.exe** file (Not what is mentioned in the Tutorial). I guess 'deu' is for the language (Deutsch in my case)

---

1. You will have to download **qc1051deu_x64.exe** from the Logitech FTP-Server: ftp://ftp.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/quickcam/
   (This link might not open in your Web-Browswer. You can usually open it by copying the link-address above into your File-Explorer)
2. Unpack the .exe file using 7Zip
3. Look in the Device Manager for an unknown device (which should be the Webcam), right-click on it and select "Update Driver".
4. Click Browse my computer for driver software and Enter or navigate to the directory where you extracted the exe

Comment: An alternative for opening the ftp link is to use Filezilla. Paste the url in the Host textfield and hit quickconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following driver files:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Logitech+QuickCam+Pro+4000

Unpacked and pointed Driver Manager at the folder.
Worked well on Windows 11.